# Is there a way to check the flow of a program one-by-one?

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, netbeans, xhtml

I need to make a sequence diagram out from JSP file (or is it JSF) which also includes xhtml and java files.

What I did before was to go to faces-config.xml and see which file the compiler will start to deploy first. Then, from there, I will go to functions one-by-one.

It's a very tiring work if I got a massive project file (which is my assignment on creating its sequence diagram).

My question is, is there any automated or at least an easy way to read the program as if it was running at a slow pace?

I'm using netbeans 7.0.1 as the IDE for JavaServer Faces compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it's called "logging".

If you don't want to do that manually, you could use a tool like AspectJ to instrument all of your app's methods and do this automatically.

There are a few tools, like [Architexa](http://www.architexa.com/index_c.php), that integrate into IDEs that do more or less the same thing, but not at run time (AFAIK).

Comment: This Architexa or any other UML modelling tools, does it supports all programming languages or just certain of it?

Comment: @amnbhrm "All?" Highly unlikely. Different tools support different languages. You'd have to look at each tool.